# One button on one side and others on other side of StackPanel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, stackpanel

I am working on a WPF application. I have a `StackPanel` in my xaml file. In StackPanel there are three buttons. Problem is that all button are either on left side or on the right side. What I want is that one button is one the left side and two buttons on the right side.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" >
    <Button Content="Open"/>
    <Button Content="Close"/>
    <Button Content="Help"/>
</StackPanel>
```

The output of this is like this.
[image: Output]

As you can see that there is a lot of space on the left side. I want my Help button to the extreme left side whil Close and Open on the extreme right. I think I can do this by implementing a grid or something like that, but I want to ask that whether I can do this with using stack panel only.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot do that with a `StackPanel`, however you don't "have" to use a `Grid`.

You can use a `DockPanel` as a compromise

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill="False">
  <Button Content="Help" DockPanel.Dock="Left" />
  <Button Content="Close" DockPanel.Dock="Right" />
  <Button Content="Open" DockPanel.Dock="Right" />
</DockPanel>
```

`LastChildFill="False"` will make sure your last added control does not end up "filling" up all the remaining space thereby giving you the look you want.

Comment: Do this inside stackPanel?

Comment: @FaisalHafeez No use a `DockPanel` instead of a `StackPanel`. It's the best solution.

Comment: @FaisalHafeez, no, it's in place of the `StackPanel`. You have to let go of the `StackPanel`.

Comment: Ok, one more scenario. What If I want two buttons on the left side and two on the right side?

Comment: Well add the new button with DockPanel.Dock="Left"

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a `Grid` for that:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Button Grid.Column="0" Content="Help"/>
    <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="Close"/>
    <Button Grid.Column="2" Content="Open"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I want to do this with StackPanel. So first question is "Is it possible or not?"

Comment: @FaisalHafeez, this is not possible with a stack panel. A stack panel by definition **stacks** its children.

Comment: Worth noting that without an explicit override, this will cause the "Help" button to stretch out, filling the available space.

Comment: @DanPuzey, nice addition. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yeh and also at times I'd normally just add a new Column exclusive for the "Help" button since then we can set all three button columns with a `IsSharedSizeScope` to maintain uniform button sizes.